# How to reset child component from parent using React Context and Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am playing with React context and hooks.I want to have a reusable Editor component in which I will be able to edit Users. Then, I will use it from NewUser and EditUser pages so that NewUser will pass an empty User and EditUser will pass an existing User.

Here is how I implemented Editor and its context

```js
const UserEditorContext = createContext({
  user: {},
  onSubmit: user => {}
});

const UserEditor = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserEditorContext);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ ...context.user });
  const setUserProp = e => setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    context.onSubmit(user);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      Username:{" "}
      <input type="text" name="username" value={user.username} onChange={setUserProp} />
      Password:{" "}
      <input type="password" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={setUserProp} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

This is how I use it from NewUser page

```js
const NewUserPage = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const createUser = user => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(user)); // todo http post
    setUser({}); // clear form. THIS DOES NOT WORK
  };
  return (
    <UserEditorContext.Provider value={{ user, onSubmit: createUser }}>
      <UserEditor />
    </UserEditorContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

### Problem

After creating a new user I want to clear the form. However my attempt to clear form, `setUser({})` does not work. It does not cause any error or anything else. It just does not update the Editor control.

Here is full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-tereshkova-dwn8h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `setUser` from `UserEditor` component to `context.onSubmit` like this:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  context.onSubmit(user, setUser);
};
```

then the `NewUserPage` component will be:

```
const NewUserPage = () => {
  const emptyUser = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  const createUser = (user, setUser) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(user)); // todo http post
    setUser(emptyUser); // clear form
  };

  return (
    <UserEditorContext.Provider value={{ user: emptyUser, onSubmit: createUser }}>
      <UserEditor />
    </UserEditorContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

working example:

[image: Edit condescending-cloud-n8138]